# Is it right to exclude (freeze) some genes from genetic operations?

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I have successfully applied NSGA-II on a multi-objective optimization problem.
While I was observing the results during the optimization process, I have noticed that some variables (genes) have reached very good values that matches my objectives, while others haven't. However during the optimization, the good genes are being frequently changed and swapped to undesired results (due to genetic operations; mutation and crossover) until the algorithm reaches a good local optima, or hits a condition.

**My question is this:**

Can I exclude some genes from the optimization process since they have already reached my condition and finally combine them with the remained genes in the final chromosome?

Comment: You're free to tweak the algorithm like you want, but if some genes can be optimized independently from the others, doesn't it mean that you should perform distinct optimizations?

Comment: @Olivier thanks for replying. The genes can't be optimized independently since they are related to each other and affect each other. What I mean by excluding genes is that those genes will not be changed or swapped anymore, but they will affect the chromosome and be taken into consideration on fitness function calculation.